# Macro for adding a worksheet name to a cell

Tags: vba, excel

First post here, and still quite a newbie at macros :-)

Is there any way that I can use a macro to insert a newly created sheet name into a cell?

I am creating a workbook for the different suppliers that we buy from.

I have a macro (from another helpful post on this forum :-)) which copies and then provides a prompt to input the supplier's name; this name is then given as the worksheet name.

I've tried to find the command to take that worksheet name and populate it into cell B1 - is it possible to do this?

My current macro is:

```
Sub New_Page()
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Sheets("Supplier")
    Dim newws As Worksheet, sh As Worksheet, newname
    Dim query As Long, xst As Boolean, info As String

    retry:
    xst = False
    newname = Application.InputBox("Enter the Supplier's name.", info, , , , , , 2)
    If newname = "False" Then Exit Sub
    For Each sh In wb.Sheets
        If sh.Name = newname Then
            xst = True: Exit For
        End If
    Next
    If Len(newname) = 0 Or xst = True Then
        info = "Sheet name is invalid. Please retry."
        GoTo retry
    End If
    ws.Copy after:=ws: Set newws = ActiveSheet: newws.Name = newname
End Sub
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Following your coding style, you can find the active command at the end of this line.

```
ws.Copy after:=ws: Set newws = ActiveSheet: newws.Name = newname: newws.Range("B1") = newws.Name
```

Given that you seem to be creating new worksheets based on a supplier's name, you might find [Can I sort by worksheet tabs](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-excel/can-i-sort-by-worksheet-tabs/9376c7d0-395d-45ed-9701-edb6a05fc527) interesting.